# Is it better to use MAE or MSE for perfomance measure?

Tags: svm, data-mining, predictive-models

My data set is about forest fires in Portugal. I want to define a model that can predict better wildfires. In my data set, the outliers are entries referring to big fires.
What is the best performance measure in this situation? I'm using the model SVM, which is the one that gives me a lower value of MAE but with RandomForest i get better values of MSE and NMSE.
I don't know what is the best in this situation.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you read http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22344/which-performance-measure-to-use-when-using-svm-mse-or-mae How does your question differ? (We can't advise well on your specific dataset on this little information.)

Comment: Yes i read it but i still don't understand which one should i use

Comment: Maybe there will never be a general answer like "MAE is better"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on what is the aim of your model; some idea is to cut your decision into 10-15 equally-sized classes and make a boxplot of error and absolute value of error; this will give you a nice insight in how the error is distributed and which overall measure handles this better, like this (on mock-up data):

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a little further how can i do that? I'm new in data mining and R. Thank you

Comment: The code for the example plot is just `plot(abs(predicted-true)~cut2(true,g=10))`; only the Hmisc package is needed to be installed and loaded first.

Comment: Analysing that plot, how can you say what may be the better measure?

Comment: The point is that you make such plots for RF and SVM, go to your forest people and discuss which distribution of error suits them better. This way you will do a *rational* choice between methods, not some random-people-on-the-internet-told-me-that-one-number-is-more-magic-than-other thing.